# VLAN inside Guest machine/domU

Tags: linux, networking, vlan

hi is it possible to create VLAN inside guest machines?

using Xen 4.2 with Ubuntu as dom0,all guests are Centos

On host i have 2 bridges in two different VLAN connected to bridge,

virtual machine has 2 NIC and connected to these bridges.

Inside VM i have only one subnet!!

since there is only one subnet and

```
route 
192.168.211.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Is it possible to configure VLAN with in VM so that both interface can work even with same subnet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both interfaces on the same subnet, you don't want to have them on separate VLANs.  If you want the VM to use both NICs in failover, then bond them into a single one.

Comment: hi this VM is part of bigger network,and i dont have different subnet inside VM,so any way to make same subnet to work,with out modifiying route tabkle